# Pointcloud transform issue

Tags: ros, transforms, ros-kinetic, image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a setup where I am fusing PointCloud2 and cameras to get XYZIRGB cloud.

```
pcl::PointCloud<XYZIRGB> points_front, points_back;
```

Both `points_back` and `points_front` come from a different lidar-camera pair. I want to publish one stream of cloud instead of two. For that I am concatenating them, but them I have to publish it with a single frame_id and that is messing where my points should show up on rviz.

```
points_front.insert(points_front.end(), points_back.begin(), points_back.end());
points_front.header.frame_id = "cam_front";
```

This will show all the points wrt front camera. Does someone have any idea for workaround this thing?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/305569/pointcloud-transform-issue/) by [Choco93](https://answers.ros.org/users/31829/choco93/) on ROS Answers with karma: 685 on 2018-10-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dhindhimathai](https://answers.ros.org/users/31021/dhindhimathai/) on 2018-10-14**:
I also think that it's an issue with not transforming the points into a single frame before concatenating them.  Just concatenating and putting the same `header.frame_id` won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

transform the entire `back` cloud into the `front` frame, concatenate them and then publish with the `front` frame?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-10-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Choco93](https://answers.ros.org/users/31829/choco93/) on 2018-10-17**:
Thanks for the responses, it worked. Can you put it as an answer so I can close the question.